# Maintain position for child in a Canvas with zoom and scroll - WPF

Tags: wpf, canvas, scroll, zooming

I would like to implement the following functionality.

I have a canvas with several `UIElements` inside it. The `Canvas` allows to zoom and scroll applying a scale and translate transforms.

[image]

I would like to maintain the red square always in the same position (left bottom corner of the `Canvas`), to behave as a floating control, so as I change the zoom or the scroll, the red square always maintains it's size and position. Something similar to google maps "Earth window":

[image]

What is the best approach to implement it?

NOTE: I tried to use the WPF [adorner layer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) but it does not respond to mouse events, and I need to interact with the red square.

Comment: Put another Panel (e.g. a Grid) on top of the Canvas, and add the Rectangle there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Clemens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1136211/clemens) said, put it in another layer on top. `Grid` can host multiple items in the same cell, so create a 1 by 1 `Grid` for your `Canvas` add content on top just like any other WPF layout. The later items appear on top (unless Z layer is specified):

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas>
        ... do all my fancy drawing
    </Canvas>
    <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100" Height="100" />
</Grid>
```

Note, you may have trouble if the canvas has any non WPF rendering, such as video or embedded WindowsForms content. I've seen people have trouble with drawing WPF stuff on top of that.

I also believe you can set `Canvas.Bottom="20"` to set the position relative to the bottom edge, but I've never used it.